# Construction of $K(\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{k}/k), 1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Take any field $k$. Is there a construction of the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{k}/k), 1)$ as a CW complex in terms of $k$?

Comment: For any group G, there is a construction of $K(G, 1)$ as a CW complex: choose a presentation. Then, begin with a single 0-cell, attach a 1-cell for each generator, and glue 2-cells in along the relations.

Comment: You might be interested more in $BGal(\bar{k}/k)$, since $Gal(\bar{k}/k)$ is topological.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what kind of construction are you looking for? $K(\mathrm{Gal}(\bar k/k),1)$ is the étale homotopy type of $k$, but I'm not sure if that would be an answer to this question.

Comment: @ArunDebray you will generally have to add more cells to kill the higher homotopy groups

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic ah that's right; thank you!

Comment: You can construct the algebraic closure from $k$. Then the Galois group and then the classifying space as the Milnor  construction. All this is master level at most.